# How do I upgrade curl in Centos 5.11?

Tags: curl, centos5

Could someone please direct me on how to upgrade curl on my centOS 5.11 server?

My current version:
curl --version
curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Answer (score 3):

1) create a new file /etc/yum.repos.d/city-fan.repo

2) Paste the following contents:

```
[CityFan]
name=City Fan Repo
baseurl=http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

3) type:

```
yum clean all
yum install curl
```

4) And it should work

Observe that for other rhel/centos versions, all you have to do is specify the appropriate city-fan url

Comment: Thank you Tbalz, that worked and now it is at the latest, however, the version displayed in phpinfo() still shows the old version even after restarting apache. Is there anything else that I would need to do?

Comment: Even if you restart lighttpd or apache service, the php-cgi processes can still be running.

In order to fix this issue, stop the service, then kill php-cgi processes
     killall php-cgi
Then started lighttpd and phpinfo is now showing that im running the new version of PHP.

Comment: Hi Tbalz, I tried what you suggested and phpinfo is still showing me the old version. I then rebooted the server and that also didn't help. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Running that command gave an error because of a conflict: see http://i.imgur.com/8Ysl52B.jpg

Comment: try running that command with the flags --skip-broken after it

Comment: hm. I tried but it tells me:   --> php55w-common conflicts with php-common
Skip-broken could not solve problems

Comment: How about yum install php55w-curl ?